# Passing value to Postgres jsonb type field with different Java data types

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jsonb

I am trying to find the easy and right way to collect different type of values and save it to Postgres 11.1 `jsonb` type column.

My entity class defines the column as

```
@Type(type = "jsonb")
@Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<SomeDetail> details;
```

And for now I have `SomeDetail` object with String types only as below

```
class SomeDetail {
  private String property;
  private String oldValue;
  private String newValue;
}
```

now since both `oldValue` and `newValue` can be of any type like String, Integer, Array and even an Object like

```
[
  { property: 'NAME', oldValue: 'Same Old Guy', newValue: 'New Awesome Guy' },
  { property: 'HOBBY', oldValue: ['hunting', 'fishing'], newValue: ['running', hiking'] },
  { property: 'ADDRESS', oldValue: { street: '123 Main St', zipCode: 12345 }, newValue: { street: '123 Wall St', zipCode: 67890 },
  { property: 'STATUS', oldValue: 'MARRIED', newValue: 'SINGLE' }
]
```

I don't think it can continue to use `SomeDetail` as it is. So my question is 
- should I just have `details` as String type so that it is just a JSON string?

The reason I am incline to (re)use `SomeDetail` is that because that is defined in Swagger (as a contract) to client that we will be returning array of above format.

Any suggestion on what/how to construct data for the `details` field so that I can easily convert back to object so that I can send back to client?

Comment: I never tried it but you can try with `Map` for some details, like `
private List<Map<String,Object>> details;`

Comment: I think real issue I am having here is since JSON can have value of any type I am trying to fig out if `details` can just be String type in Entity class such that i will create JSON string and save to DB. The issue I will face will probably face is when I read back from DB as now I have to cast as `SomeDetail` for each entry.

Comment: Or maybe another question will be what the type of field should be for `details` when sending  to the clinet?